# which VM should I target for my oracle database?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I configured two different virtual machine for oracle database, but I am confused on which network adapter I should use. 
I have 2 databases on 2 different VMwares and when I do tnsping alias name it gives me this error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable
```

Here is my tns entry:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oel-12c)(PORT = 1521))
ORANC1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =  192.168.222.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORANC1)
    )
  )
```

I checked all listeners, database status and all tns entry and listener.

I feel that my network adapter issue between NAT, HOSTonly, bridge.

Thanks

Comment: 192.168.222.0 is a network address; what address does `oel-12c` resolve to?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you might not have an entry in your tnsnames.ora file for ORCL. The listener output suggests it's not started. Try from cmd

Also make sure your host address is entered correctly.

```
echo %ORACLE_HOME%
echo %ORACLE_SID%
set oracle_sid=ORCL
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Copy and paste the output exactly as it appears.

Comment: I checked everything . Everything is good and set . I configured 2 Virtual machine in Vmware workstation. I think that its not possible to ping/tnsping  2  different oracle database configured in 2 different Virtual machine . Because its related to network configuration issue in VM and not database issue.